# Java generics : type inference

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, inference

Hi I'm trying to get ArrayList of generic type to infer ( instantiate ? ) an actual type, yet Java seem intent on setting my generic type as the most general type possible - Object.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class test {

    public static <T,U> void tryInstantialGenericType(ArrayList<T> tArray, ArrayList<U> uArray) { 
        for (T tObject: tArray) {
            if (tObject != null) {
                uArray.add((U) tObject);
            } // cast type T elements in a to type U, then add to uArray.
        }
        System.out.println(uArray);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        ArrayList na=new ArrayList<>(); 
        na.add(23.56);
        na.add(12.456);
        ArrayList<String> as=new ArrayList<>();
        as.add("dfty");
        tryInstantialGenericType(na,as); 
    }
}
```

The idea here is doubles can be cast to Strings, but Strings can't be cast to doubles. So by swapping na and as, it should be possible to alternative between successful runs and some sort of error, compiletime or runtime. 
But that's not what happens. 
Instead in both cases, the type of the parameter ArrayLists a & c don't get inferred to be Strings or doubles, they get inferred to be some sort of general carry-all ArrayLists, capable of accepting any object.
Why is it doing this? Am I wrong to think generic types are supposed to infer to a specific type?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but generic types have nothing to do with runtime. Only compile time. In runtime, all generic types are erased. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: Also, you are using raw types: `ArrayList` - this is *not* the same as an `ArrayList<?>` or `ArrayList<Object>`.

Comment: 1. You're using a raw type (ArrayList), thus ruining any type-safety that generics bring. 2. You seem to think that a Double can be cast to a String. No, it can't Double is not a subclass of String, so a Double is not a STring, so you can't cast a Double to a String. That said, I don't understand the rest of your question, but I think you should start by learning the basics of types before diving into generics.

Comment: Very few of the things you said are true.  Doubles can't be cast to Strings.  All ArrayLists can accept all objects if you do unsafe casts like the ones you're doing.

Comment: In short, what you're attempting cannot be done.